# Histogram from Spherical Plots in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a data in azimuth and elevation angles with radius 1, e.g., `point = [azimuth, elevation, radius]`. I would like to divide the sphere surface into 64 regions and get a histogram of the points. For example, in the image below, there are 12 points in the first bin (`0 deg <= azimuth < 45 deg`,`0 deg <= elevation < 45 deg`)

[image]

I am thinking of using Switch/Case to group the points but that would definitely be very inefficient. Is there any better way?

Edited: I would like to find a way to label the regions (any way will do) and get a histogram, e.g `myHist = [... 1 1 ... 10 3 ... ]`
[image]

Comment: Do you want those colored "fields" as borders for your bins in z-direction? And is your data allways in a unit sphere(Radius=1)? How many different "fields" do you want in  z-axis?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23897-n-dimensional-histogram)? I could also think of a way to do it using the built-in [hist3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html).

Comment: The data always have radius=1. There're eight fields in x-y direction (azimuth: 0-45,45-90,...) and z-axis(elevation: 0-45,45-90,...) respectively. So total 64 fields.

Comment: @Dev-iL I agree, I think hist3 should do it.

Comment: @Dev-iL I'm not sure whether that's what I want to achieve. I just need a 2-D histogram with the 64 bins (regions of the sphere) as the x-axis, and the number of points in each region as y-axis.

Comment: @boogiedoll - run hist3 on (az,el) and then just convert the 2D indices of the resulting bins to 1D ones (e.g. using `reshape`, or according to some other logic you dictate).

Comment: BTW, MATLAB excpects the azimuth angle to be in the range (-180,180) and the elevation (-90,90), according to this page: www.mathworks.com/help/phased/ug/spherical-coordinates.html .  Bottom line - elevation changes in steps of 22.5 degrees, and not 45 :)

Comment: @Dev-iL you're right. Will try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not completely sure about it, test it with your data, see how it goes,

```
r = ones(1,100);
a = 2*pi*rand(1,100);
e = 2*pi*rand(1,100);
[X,Y,Z] = sphere(8) ;
[x y z] = sph2cart(a,e,r);
surf(X,Y,Z);hold on;
plot3(x,y,z,'ko','MarkerFaceColor','k');
axis([-1 1 -1 1 -1 1]);
fields = linspace(0,2*pi,9);
c = {fields,fields};
Hist = hist3(cat(2,a',e'),'Edges',c);
Hist(:,end) = []; Hist(end,:) = [];
```

[image]

```
 Hist =
 2     1     0     2     2     2     1     0
 0     0     2     1     2     2     3     2
 1     2     3     2     0     4     4     2
 1     0     0     1     1     2     1     4
 0     3     1     1     4     1     3     1
 3     3     1     3     4     1     1     0
 1     5     2     1     0     0     2     0
 0     0     3     1     1     0     2     2

 sum(sum(Hist)) = 100;
```

I think it could be better if you use `bar3`

[image]

Comment: Instead of the 2-D Hist array, can I get a vector, like the one I added in the question?

Comment: @boogiedoll You could `reshape` the `Hist`.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to obtain coordinates for text labels, you can use `[N,c] = hist3(...)`, where `c` contains bin centers.

Comment: now instead of getting the count of the points in each field, can I get the field index/label for each point? Like in the above answer, let say point(1) = field?, point(2) = field?, etc

Comment: In a loop it can be done, if you want it without loop then it's better to ask a new question, so others could help too.

Comment: could you show a simple example to do it using a loop?